# How to get InvoiceId from sales_order_invoice_pay in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, invoice, sales-invoice

How to get invoiceId from sales_order_invoice_pay event.

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice->getIncrementId();
```

Can't get with this code But with sales_order_invoice_save_after event I can get the ID.

Can anyone help me out to get invoiceId from **sales_order_invoice_pay**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sales_order_invoice_pay` can provide order objects.From that order object, you **can get invoices of an order, that can multiple invoices or single invoice**.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$invoiceList = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
if (count($invoiceList->getItems()) > 1) {
    foreach ($invoiceList as $invoice){
        $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }
}
```